# Is there a simple apt command for upgrade to a "point" release? eg, from 18.04 -> 18.04.2

Tags: apt, upgrade

So I installed 18.04 LTS from `.iso`, and am mainly interested in stability over "having the latest".

I have seen that 18.04.2 is released, but the documentation suggests downloading a fresh `.iso`, which seems like a lot of install work (and risk) for a minor point release.

Surely there must be a simple `apt` command which does this, similar to if I was upgrading from 16.04 or 17.* releases?

Note: I do **not** want to upgrade to 18.10 or 19.04 at this time.

Comment: `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` is enough

Comment: I thought it might be, but I could not find that explicitly confirmed in any docs

Comment: Yeah I can't find that too. The point releases are like normal updates with major updates bundled up. Repositories remain same. And I believe APT takes care of it automatically, that's why it was not documented.

Comment: Note that the point releases after .1 will have the HWE packages for a later kernel, some of which will be supported for only 9 months.